# Am I wasting my time and moderators time by flagging junk?

Tags: discussion, support

Occasionally I find junk, sometimes old junk. They're usually answers that are bad (comments, product promotions, etc) which I discover as I'm reading through random posts looking for answers to things. Most recently, I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/688864/562566).

Here is a quote of this answer, in case the link disappears:

> *> Here's a function I coded for you*
>
> Very bad.
>   psapi must not be linked statically (never)!
>
> See MSDN samples.

As you can see, it's total garbage. Also, the user's account appears to be gone. So I naturally thought "this answer needs to be gone, user is gone, only moderator can handle" and I flagged.

The flag however, was declined:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

This response is puzzling to me. To me, there is no other course of action here. But this moderator appears to have decided that this isn't an issue. It's a little confusing and disheartening to get a response like this. But this isn't about my feelings, it's about understanding the current policy, because I don't want to waste my time or the mods' time. Can someone clarify? Has policy changed, is there an unwritten rule that old garbage is okay garbage? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I'd have flagged "not an answer" -- then the community can deal with it.

Comment: Funnily enough, your quotation of the answer misses the fact that *it failed to format its own quotation correctly*, which in itself contributes even more to the answer being garbage.

Comment: Everyday I read on meta about valid flags being declined. It seems as if some moderators don't have the time to see if the flags are valid, and "decline" becomes a default option. The good news is that meta posts like this (although they take up much more of your and our time) have the desired effect. What we need to realise is that with all the flags, the moderators don't have the time.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Beware of selection bias: probably a huge majority of flagged posts are handled exactly the way they should be, and so nobody posts about them. You only see the ones on meta where something unusual has happened, because that's the only thing that (a) gets someone to post about it, and (b) collects upvotes. I wouldn't come to the conclusion that moderators just choose "decline" because they don't have time to figure out the right thing to do. Often, as in this case, the moderator's action was correct in the end anyway.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire You are taking this way too personally. Nobody is trying to punish you, and declining a flag is no punishment even if they wanted to. Nobody is accusing you of rep-farming - you don't even get rep for meta posts. The comment of mine that made you so upset isn't even addressed to you at all, it is reminding another commenter about how to keep perspective on what happens on meta.

Comment: @amalloy yes you put it better than me. I was trying to say its about improving state, but not about perfection. In order to process so many flags (mostly correctly), it is acceptable that some are wrong. In the time taken to process 1 unclear flag, they could clean up 10 others.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Most of the flags being brought up on Meta look, to me, like people flagging for moderator attention when another flag would be more valid. In this case, it should have been flagged NAA. Could the mod deal with it while they're there? Sure. But, that would teach people it's ok to flag for mod attention when it's not necessary. I think, overall the mods are doing a good job teaching people to use the right flag, so the mods can deal with things that only mods can deal with.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You are right on this being garbage. Moreover, it is a reply to the post of Irwin, which makes it ['not an answer'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/245360). You shouldn't have flagged it with a custom reason.

You should flag it as NAA, which I did. I also downvoted and voted to delete. Hope it is gone soon.

Comment: Ah, this may have been where I messed up. I didn't choose the right flag.

Comment: That is not what the description says and usually a moderator will point you to that (since you can learn from it). I guess they just made a mistake. Doesn't matter though. We will get it fixed.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire As a general rule: *avoid* custom flags. Those are only for peculiar cases that *cannot* be handled using close votes/other flags and *they are easily declined*. Moreover if you use one, be very detailed in the message you put. It's well known that moderators do *not* see much context about the flagged item when handling flags and so something that's obvious to you looking at the question & answers may not be obvious when handling the flag in the moderator tools UI. There's plently of question about declined flags due to this fact.

Comment: "It's well known that moderators do not see much context about the flagged item" -- maybe if you're a moderator, or follow meta very closely! Most of us don't; I myself only make it over here if there's something that catches my eye in the "Hot Meta Posts" box.

Answer (score 15):

There are two flags you could use in this case: *"not an answer"* or *"very low quality"*, the latter appearing after a down vote.

Both of these flags end up in the low quality review queue, which is handled by high rep users. Five such users get to review it before the flag is accepted or declined.

So usually, these flags are handled correctly, but not always so. There are "robo-reviewers" who don't check the post too carefully, and if you are unlucky you get several robo-reviewers at the same time, your flag might end up incorrectly accepted/declined.

Now there is also the custom flagging option, which only diamond mods can review. You should not use this option unless there is something quite special with the post, such as for example edit wars between several high rep users, close/delete voters going bananas on perfectly on-topic questions etc etc.

Comment: Ultimately, robo-reviewing happens because of the core design flaw of SO: the assumption that people with excellent technical knowledge automatically make great moderators, which is simply not true. Similarly, "rep farmers" don't necessarily make great moderators either, more likely the contrary.

Comment: Meh.... you don't even have to _pretend_ to have "excellent technical knowledge" to fuck up the act of reviewing SO posts. The reputation threshold is ludicrously low.

Comment: People in general are terrible moderators. That's why we're very careful about who gets appointed to leadership positions (here and in life in general), and even then we get it wrong an awful lot (just check out workplace.se and other places where people are dealing with terrible management.) SE I would say does a better job than most of the internet keeping its moderation team decent, but even it has its flaws.